# Recursive Apple ID password procedure?

Tags: email, password, apple-id

One of my friends has forgotten his Apple ID password and is attempting to reset it. I told him to go to [Apple's password reset page](https://iforgot.apple.com/), which he has done. He opted for email authentication/reset since he's also forgotten his security question/answer.

When he does this, he receives this email.

> Dear <s>Xxxxx Xxxxxx</s>,
>
> The password for your Apple ID <s>xxx.xxx@xxx.co.uk</s> has been
>   successfully reset.
>
> If you believe you have received this email in error, or that an
>   unauthorized person has accessed your account, please go to
>   iforgot.apple.com to reset your password immediately. Then review and
>   update your security settings at appleid.apple.com >
>
> Questions? There are lots of answers on our Apple ID support page >
>
> Thanks, Apple Customer Support

At no point was he prompted to enter a new password, so I don't see how it can have been successfully reset (and to what?). Going back to iforgot.apple.com results in the same email.

I've tried resetting my own password, and I receive an email that takes me a form to enter a new password, after which I then receive the email above - so it works perfectly. What is going on?

Edit:

I've just noticed that more than one email address can be associated with an Apple account. Is it possible that the email I received that took me to the password reset form is being sent to a secondary email (he doesn't know whether he set any up)? If that's the case, surely that must mean that somebody is reading his old email account and processing the reset request for him to receive the confirmation to his primary email address? All this seems a little odd.

Answer (score 1):

First, just clearing my doubt, did he try checking the mail in a popular browser or any device? , just a guess, may be due to the browser agent, he might not be able to view the image or link.

Now if this is not working he has another option to use the secret question option. If he doesn't remember that , just ask him to mail apple support with his mail id and username ,and they can help you , they really do too..

Comment: Hi iGameRam. Yes, he's checked his emails on his phone, laptop and iPad, including junk mail folders etc, with no joy. He doesn't remember the answer to his secret question. Looks like we'll have to try and resort to Apple support, I don't know how helpful they can be though - he doesn't have a lot more information he can give them, and they can't make the procedures for password resets too lax or that would be a security concern.

Comment: Actually if he can provide the userid and the Email account linked to it, they can manually send him them password reset email id to recover his account. Also let them know the default mail recovery didn't work, they can definitely help.

Comment: Great, I'll definitely get him to give that a try and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, he's checked his emails on his phone, laptop and iPad, including junk mail folders etc, with no joy. He doesn't remember the answer to his secret question. Looks like we'll have to try and resort to Apple support, I don't know how helpful they can be though - he doesn't have a lot more information he can give them, and they can't make the procedures for password resets too lax or that would be a security concern. – Anonymous Jul 6 at 12:57