# How to contact Apple if somebody has created an AppleID using an email address of mine.

Tags: security, apple-id, password, accounts, authentication

**Before** you downvote this question consider that I'm not the first to run into Apple's odd [recursive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55691/112208) authentication [loop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/105175/112208).

Frustrated Apple User [sums](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244373/112208) it up as:

> So Apple could do nothing and this guy is allowed to use my email as
>   his apple ID as long as he wants and I will receive emails from Apple
>   when he uses his device, etc.

It's an [established](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72554/112208) problem with Apple authorization and authentication.  (My account is gmail, but it's basically the same underlying problem.)

While probably not a phishing attack, it certainly could be malicious.

---

Apple [wrote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/346719/112208):

> Thanks for contacting us. I'm sorry that you weren't able to reset
>   your Apple ID password. I’ll do everything that I can to get your
>   issue resolved. If you haven’t already, you can try resetting your
>   password online at: http://iforgot.apple.com For more information on
>   resetting your security questions, see this page:
>   https://support.apple.com/HT201485 For security reasons, I can't help
>   you access this account via email.

So far as I know **my** account has been hijacked.  I say **my** account, because it's **my** e-mail address which is used to login.  So far as I know this is some variant of a malicious social engineering attack.

How do I contact Apple by [chat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/346745/112208)?

When I try to contact Apple through Chat I get:

[image: secret question]

and so cannot proceed with resetting the password.

Notably, signing up for a mailing list has **better** authentication and authorization.

Or, an e-mail address for Apple would be a good way to enter into a dialogue with them.  Do they have an e-mail address?  Their e-mail to me came from `appstore_emea@apple.com` but they've already explained that they won't reset the password via e-mail.

*When I try to contact Apple support through their website it goes in a loop where they want my Apple ID and then challenge me with secret questions.*

At best it's annoying.  At worst it's some sort of attack.  This has been going on at least since 2016, we're almost in 2019.

This is the e-mail, or a portion of:

```
Welcome to iCloud.
Your Apple ID is <me>@gmail.com.
iCloud keeps all your photos and videos, documents, contacts, and more up to date automatically, so you always have access to the latest versions on all your devices.
```

Comment: Why not confirm the phone number?

Comment: I've tried, @SolarMike.  I cannot answer the secret question.  In this case, phone number.

Comment: Why don't you just ring them? Google 'contact apple' to get your country's variant on this - https://www.apple.com/contact/ I had a similar issue with an Amazon account & got it sorted within the day, by being able to reply to them from the email address whilst we were talking on the phone [I also own the domain so they could look me up on whois]

Comment: @Tetsujin "...got off the phone with a rep from Apple and they said there is nothing they can do to help." -frustrated apple user

Comment: If I understand you correctly, somebody else used a string matching your Gmail address as their AppleID identifier, right? And you tried to contact Apple based on the AppleID with your Gmail adress?

Comment: @Thufir why can't you provide the phone number you used with your Apple ID?
- Did you change it?
- Do you think the criminal who stole your account changed it?

Comment: Or, in other words, can you describe the part of your problem which can not be answered by referring you to https://www.apple.com/contact/ (or the equivalent for your country)?

Comment: I've e-mailed Apple.  Based on linked questions Apple will do nothing about it.  I don't know that it's benign at all.  everything I see says that Apple will ignore the problem as that's been what others have posted here.  That there's no solution at all.  So, I'm asking:  can I not register my e-mail as an apple ID?  Note that in their e-mail to me, Apple say that the ID is my e-mail.  Again, the ID is my e-mail.  it's my ID by their own phrasing.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I don't know.  Maybe a criminal registered my e-mail.  There's no way to know at all, and, based on other comments linked, no way to find out.  We'll see what Apple replies, but, based on other comments, their response will be to shrug their shoulders and that there's nothing they can do.

Comment: @nohillside so far as I know Apple won't respond.  I'm hoping there's a way to "re-register" or otherwise gain control of **my** Apple ID:  which is **my** e-mail address.  I'm asking how to contact Apple in the context of not having an Apple ID which I can login with, as an Apple ID seems required to contact Apple.  Catch 22.

Comment: AppleIDs and email addresses are two different things. Did somebody else register an AppleID with your email address, or did you?

Comment: au contrair mon ami, Apple wrote to me:  "Welcome to iCloud.
Your Apple ID is <me>@gmail.com" so, no my Apple ID **is** my e-mail address which has been, arguably, hijacked.  This question is solely:  how do I contact Apple by e-mail or chat?  ***That's the scope of the question.***

Comment: Did you personally create an AppleID with this gmail address? Or did you just receive the email out of the blue?

Comment: @nohillside - Someone *else* created an Apple ID account and his email got used.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346719/how-to-unlock-an-apple-id-through-e-mail

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting us to be able to do to fix this or even advise you as *we're not Apple, nor does Apple read these Q&A in any official capacity.*  However, in an attempt to assist, can you **please tell us what your email looks like.**  I don't need the actual address; obfuscate it somehow.  If your name is John Smith and your address is john.smith@gmail.com, say "first.last@gmail.com" or something similar.

Comment: I added a portion of the e-mail.  I just want to chat or e-mail Apple.  I've replied to their e-mail but don't expect a dialogue from what might be a no-reply e-mail.  My original title was:  how to chat with Apple?  That's the question:  how do I chat or e-mail Apple so that I get something more than just a form letter.  As to it being benign, there's no way to know.  That's the point.  It raises red flags at a minimum.  And has been doing so with others going back years, at least since 2015.  And, yes, even according to wikipedia, the apple ID **is** the e-mail address.

Comment: Please focus your question on the actual problem (contacting Apple) you want to solve. I understand your frustration, but AD is not the place to discuss Apple‘s actions, or lack thereof.

Comment: @nohillside in all fairness, that was the original title.  I just wanted to chat with Apple over IRC/web/etc.  Don't relish calling them.  If they reply to the e-mail in a meaningful way that would be great.  I don't see why they don't call the phone number for the account, which is what I asked them to do.

Comment: Chatting will not help if you can‘t prove that the email is yours, and you are the person they are chatting with. Same applies for the phone number (Apple has no way of verifying who picks up the phone and whether what they answer is true).

Comment: good grief, of course I can prove that the **email** is mine.  they could, for example, just reset the password via e-mail.  They flat out refuse to do so.  Kinda the point.  Which is why I want to chat with them.

Comment: So anybody walking up to your unlocked computer, or hacking your Gmail account, could easily change the password for your AppleID? I‘m quite happy to know that this is not possible without additional steps.

Comment: @Thufir was your Gmail password stolen? You can check this through 2 ways: • you received an E-mail from Apple to check your E-mail address and this confirmation wasn’t expected (i.e. a criminal using your Gmail account answered in place of you), • on this web server: https://haveibeenpwned.com/

Comment: This is happening to me right now. My email account shows no other logins besides me. I've sent the apple accounts emails directly to spam. So far they've opened an Apple ID, Icloud and Apple TV account with my email without apparently being able to verify their email address. I was able to reset the password on the apple account but couldn't log in without the security question which in itself is massively flawed. Apple needs to get their security together. I've never opened a link from any of the emails which are: <appleid@id.apple.com> <noreply@apple.com> <noreply@email.apple.com> Assuming

Comment: and yet the overwhelming response here is "well, it isn't your account" @MrNobody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue here, Allan's answer is unhelpful and presumptuous that it is "impossible" for an email address to be tied up to an Apple ID without being verified.

Although it has not been verified, the email address is still unavailable for anyone else (like the actual owner of the address) to use.

Comment: thanks for chiming and confirming what should, frankly, be obvious and non-controversial.  Answer accepted.

Comment: I don't really understand how Allan thinks that because it was user error by his clients, it must be user error by everyone else. He is talking about confirmation bias, but his clients are simply reinforcing his own bias! My email address is tied up with someone else's Apple account - my email is NOT hacked (it is a Google account so I can see exactly where it's been accessed), the verification link has NOT been clicked by me or anyone else, but it still tied up in that Apple account. IT rule no 1: there is no "this cannot happen" rule.

Answer (score 3):

> How to contact Apple if **somebody has created an AppleID using an email address of mine.**

This particular answer is meant to address the qualifier (emphasized)  portion of the question.

#### Unless your email address is not 100% solely in your control, this cannot happen.

Why? Because immediately upon creating an AppleID, you are immediately asked to confirm the account and an email is with with a *code only*; there are no links to click or addresses to reply to.

[image]
[image]

To be perfectly clear, an AppleID ***cannot*** be created unless someone physically types out the confirmation code in the boxes on Apple's AppleID website.

#### What this means

If "someone", whether nefarious or innocent intentions, created an AppleID account with your email address they either had:

- access your email account
- access to a trusted device that's no longer in your possession (sold, gifted, or stolen)
- you confirmed the account and forgot about it.

#### What is Apple going to do?

**Nothing, unless you can authenticate with the credentials the account creator provided.**

- email address
- Birthday
- Phone Number (required in some countries)
- 3 different security questions with 6 options each as to the question being asked (18 different permutations)

Apple needs to validate who you are before it will even contemplate making a change.  The reason for the extra verification credentials is for the simple reason email addresses and phone numbers change; your birthday and the city where your parents met (one of the questions) will not.

> So far as I know my account has been hijacked. I say my account, because it's my e-mail address which is used to login. So far as I know this is some variant of a malicious social engineering attack.

It could be your account and equally as likely it's not.   We (here on Ask Different) and Apple only have your word that the email is in fact "yours."  How do we know that you haven't compromised the legitimate AppleID account owner and you're attempting to hack their credentials? How secure would AppleID be if they allowed anyone to merely claim an email address was theirs and to reset the password?

(It's not an accusation, it's an academic exercise)

I can already hear your argument:  *It's my email account.*  Ok, let's look at it from Apple's prospective:

- Given the security process, your email must have been compromised when it was created
- Given that you can't authenticate any other security credential, but claiming you've got access to email means email is potentially compromised now.

From Apple's perspective, it's not their problem.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks Allan. I wonder whether the "verify with code" part also happens if one creates a new AppleID during the setup of a new Mac or a new iDevice?

Comment: @nohillside - I don't have a new Apple device to test on (Santa/St. Nick/Kris Kringle/Father Christmas, et. al was good, just not *that good*), but I don't think it would matter.  The email address would have to be validated meaning either account was compromised or the user validated and forgot.

Comment: This is why I was concerned:  the e-mail account must've been compromised by your answer.  Are you absolutely positive of that?  Because by your answer there's a bad actor involved somewhere.  (I take your rhetorical point that maybe that's "me" -- but it's not.  Trust me.)  I'm going to re-enable MFA on my gmail and change the password, but that doesn't give me access to "my" or "the" Apple ID for my e-mail account.  Leaving open just for a bit.  Thx.

Comment: @Thufir was your Gmail password stolen? You can check this through 2 ways: • you received an E-mail from Apple to check your E-mail address and this confirmation wasn’t expected (i.e. a criminal using your Gmail account answered in place of you), • on this web server: http://haveibeenpwned.com .

Comment: I will add that, for my spam-trap gmail account, I believe I created an account some time ago for an Apple ID.   That Apple ID was definitely compromised, because my "name" is not what I would use, but I was able to regain control via e-mail.  **I don't believe it's required to authenticate with a code** to setup an Apple ID.  But, I don't know that for a fact.  Hopefully Apple will respond to my second e-mail to them.  (I don't really mind that much that my spam-trap account was compromised, insofar as the Apple ID.  Neither here nor there.)

Comment: I can't tell you if/when/why your email was compromised.  You could have been given an iPod as a gift by a significant other (with access to your email) who set the account up for you or your email could have been hacked and every/anything in between.  The point is Apple can't confirm who you say you are and that's why you're getting nowhere with them.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct simply based on the fact that **others report the same problem**.  That is, that their e-mail account is used to create an Apple ID without ever requiring a confirmation e-mail.  Let's turn this around:  let's say that I buy an iPhone.  Can I not now use **my** e-mail to register an iCloud account?  After all, it's **my** e-mail.  Which Apple has now associated with secret questions, like a phone number, entered by another.

Comment: @Thufir - belief is not proof. Secondly, I used an **existing** iCloud account (not previously used for an AppleID) to create this example.  Finally, if you’ve ever worked in tech support, you’d know that multiple people reporting the same thing is not always a failure of the techn oftentimes it’s a failure of the user.

Comment: good grief, @Allan, I never claimed proof.  But let's explore that:  what "proof" would you accept?  So far as I can tell someone entered **my** e-mail address for **their** iCloud account.  The e-mail I received **from** Apple certainly didn't say that was impossible at all.

Comment: @Thufir - you made a definitive statement (*you don't believe it's correct*) and then attempted to back it up with anecdotal evidence (*other people experienced it*).  This is a very common occurrence especially in Apple forums where people want to *believe* something is so then find "proof" through the musings of others  - aka confirmation bias.   The proof (in all cases) would be to *replicate* the issue so that a definitive outcome could be accurately predicted (i.e. create an new email account somewhere and attempt to sign up for an Apple ID).  Short of that, it's nothing but conjecture.

Comment: Let's do this, @Allan :  I'll forward you the actual e-mail **from** Apple where they acknowledge that it's entirely possible for another person to register **my** e-mail account **without** access to my actual e-mail.

Comment: I encourage any and all to read the accepted answer and ignore the wrong information in this "answer" which is, at best, misinformation.

Comment: no, @Allan your logic is flawed.  let's do this:  you create a gmail account, then tell me.  I'll "register" it as an apple id with my phone number, then you complain to apple.  they'll say:  oh, what phone number did you register it with?  You have your assumptions wrong.  because then the account is in limbo.  neither party can fully authenticate.  do you not understand??

Comment: I already tested it by doing **exactly** that.  The only one here making assumptions is you.  I have hard evidence.  I literally gave you screen shots of emails.  All you have is comments, but I get it, you don’t want to admit you made a mistake.

Comment: LoL, that you were unable to register such an e-mail doesn't preclude that it's possible.  My agenda?  Just want to gain control of *my* iCloud (or whatever) account which was registered by someone else probably with the new purchase of an iPhone where, yes, they entered their phone number.  Read again the corrospondence from Apple, they certainly don't deny its possibility.

Comment: Of course they don't deny the possibility - it's a legal thing!  You don't seem to get it... someone could have had your email address before you, you could have erred, or you could have been hacked.  The point is, your account was created with a phone number and security questions YOU can't authenticate.  How is Apple supposed to verify that?  It's not your iCloud account simply because you now happen to have an email address that was used previously.

Comment: @Allan This same thing is happening to me right now, but I can confirm that they don't have access to my email address, and never did. I received:

1. A new Apple ID creation email, 2. An email telling me that a device has logged into an iCloud account (not mine, new Apple ID), and 3. An email asking me to confirm my email address.

The email address is actually not even my email; it's a variant missing a period in my actual email that string matches to the same email. (See here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en)

They don't even know my actual Gmail address.

Answer (score 2):

I have this situation with a domain we purchased from another person who happened to set up an AppleID account with it before we purchased the domain-—so we now have the same email address but we can't reset the appleID with it alone--but we do get all AppleID related email intended for the previous owner.

I'm not sure how to deal with that problem——but it is an example of this happening without losing control of an email address. Instead, we purchased a domain that expired and had email addresses on it we are re-using, so to speak, that have AppleIDs tied to them.